# Flutter returns "Instance of Future<int>" instead of expected value

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have this code:

```
class SharedPreferencesHelper {
  static Future<int> getYear() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print("GET1");
    print(prefs.getInt("year"));
    return prefs.getInt("year");
  }
}
```

`print` above correctly outputs `2019` on `GET1` (I indeed set `prefs.setInt('year', 2019)`)

```
year = SharedPreferencesHelper.getYear();
print("GET2");
print(year);
```

But `print` above return `Instance of Future<int>` on `GET2`, but I expected `2019`.

I've been checked the `awaits`/`async`, I kinda confused where do I am missing.

I need to use the `2019` value to be used on `DateTime.parse()`.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also await the second call to SharedPreferences

```
year = await SharedPreferencesHelper.getYear();
```